# concatMap() behavior in a pipe()

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to understand behavior of concatMap() operator. I wrote some [example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zggqxc?file=index.ts)

```
import './style.css';

import { concatMap, fromEvent, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
const button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
const obs1 = fromEvent(button1, 'click');
const obs2 = fromEvent(button2, 'click');
const obs3 = fromEvent(button3, 'click');

obs1
  .pipe(
    concatMap((obs1value) => {
      console.log('obs1:', obs1value);
      return obs2; // wait for this to complete before merging next value
    }),
    concatMap((obs2value) => {
      console.log('obs2', obs2value);
      return obs3; // wait for this to complete before merging next value
    })
  )
  .subscribe((obs3value) => {
    console.log('obs3:', obs3value);
  });

// button2.click() // nothing
// button3.click() // nothing

button1.click(); // obs1
button2.click(); // obs2
button3.click(); // obs3

button1.click(); // nothing -???
button2.click(); // nothing -???

button3.click(); // obs3
button3.click(); // obs3
button3.click(); // obs3
```

Initially after button 1, button 2 and button 3 are clicked, I can see the print statements. However after that for button1 and button2, there are no print statements, it is observed only in case of button3. I see RxJS documentation says concatMap() would be "...waiting for each one to complete before merging the next". But since obs1, obs2 and obs3 have not completed yet, why do I see the print statement even once?

If I change the code slightly https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zggqxc, to complete observable as below

```
obs3.pipe(first());
```

Now licking button1, why is nothing is printed?

```
button1.click(); // obs1
button2.click(); // obs2
button3.click(); // obs3

button1.click(); // nothing -???
button2.click(); // obs2
button3.click(); // obs3
button3.click(); // nothing
button3.click(); // nothing
button2.click(); // obs2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you are using `concatMap`, with the emphasis on `map`.
Mapping will not just concatenate all observables but replace (map) items from the previous observable with a sequence of other items.

For each item from your "outer" observable which is actually mapped to another "inner" observable, your map callback (parameter of `concatMap(...)`) is executed once when the mapping actually occurs.

When are those mappings performed? - `concatMap` will take one item from the outer observable and then defers handling all other items from the outer observable until the inner observable (returned by the map callback) completes. The outer observable's items are indeed buffered until the inner observable completes.

Side note: In a synchronous scenario this is roughly comparable to `SelectMany` from C# or `flatMap` from Java Streams API.

Let me describe your first use scenario:

1. Each item in `obs1` will be replaced by the sequence of items from `obs2`.

   - When this replacement is evaluated by pressing `button1` (you might have implemented it in a way which depends on the value you received from obs1!), the first log output becomes visible.
   - Further clicks are on `button1` will be ignored until `obs2` has completed.
2. Each item of `obs2` will be replaced by the sequence of items from `obs3`.

   - Again, when the replacement gets evaluated by pressing `button2`, the second log output becomes visible.
   - Further clicks on `button2` will be ignored until `obs3` has completed.

Therefore, when pressing `button1`, `button2` and `button3` you are essentially just subscribed to `obs3`.
As `obs3` never finishes, you will indeed never see any other output.

In your second scenario the observable you map to `obs2` is `obs3.pipe(take(1))` which completes after one click on `button3`.
As soon as that happens, the pipeline will will continue to map items from `obs2`. The next mapping happens as soon as one item in `obs2` becomes available (which is immediately, if `button2` has been clicked intermediately or later as soon as it gets clicked) and then one click to `button3` is awaited again.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `button1.click();` second time the `next` notification is emitted but `obs2` hasn't completed yet so the project function in `concatMap()` isn't invoked. Only if `obs2` completed then `concatMap()` would pop the oldest notification stacked and passed it to its project function.

If you log `next` notifications comming from `obs1` you'll see the event being emitted.

```
...

obs1
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    concatMap((obs1value) => {
      console.log('obs1:', obs1value);
      return obs2; // wait for this to complete before merging next value
    }),
...
```